# I have a mac and Dr java isn't running my programs at all

Tags: java, macos, drjava

Dr java compiles my code just fine, however, it doesn't run them at all, it only prints "Static Error: This class does not have a static void main method accepting String[]." . I tried the exact code on windows and it worked perfectly. I don't know where's the problem coming from. Is it my mac, my code, or Dr java?

I wish that I could provide an image of what's happening. It seems that I can't at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You should add this method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //do whatever
}
```

to your `public` class (that you want to be the starting point of your program).

Note: Remember that every thing in the signature of `main` method should be exactly as I've shown except the name of argument (args) that you can change it as you wish.